# Passing an object by reference in Java

Tags: java, reference

Okay, so I have the following code.

Main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer val = 20;
        User user = new User(val);
        System.out.println(user.getVar());
        val = 21;
        System.out.println(user.getVar());
    }
}
```

User class

```
public class User {

    private Integer var;

    public Integer getVar() {
        return var;
    }

    public void setVar(Integer var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public User(Integer var) {
        this.var = var;
    }
}
```

The thing I struggle to understand is why the value in User class doesn't change when we change its reference in Main class. How can we change a value in User class changing the reference of the object anyway? I clearly don't understand something crucial about passing an object by reference and I'll be really glad if someone clarifies this moment for me.

Comment: `Integer` is [**immutable**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html). `int[]` or `AtomicInteger` would work as you expected.

Comment: Even if `Integer` was not immutable, assigning a new object to an existing reference does not automatically assign that object to all other references to the original object.

Comment: The "value" that you are changing _is the variable's reference to the `Integer` object_.

Comment: The part you're missing is call **auto-boxing**, which is where the compiler changes your code from `val = 21;` to `val = Integer.valueOf(21);`, which is almost the same as `val = new Integer(21);`, except that `valueOf()` returns cached values for some numbers. As you can see, the statement doesn't update the `Integer` object, it replaces the object with another object.

Comment: This is a very good article to start with: https://javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp